# can I get ConEmu to "mark to copy"?

Tags: conemu

I installed ConEmu last week, thought I'd give it a try vs. Console2. After staring at various config options for 10 minutes I didn't see any way to get ConEmu to automatically copy text that I've selected to the clipboard. Console2 will do it.

Is there a config option for this that I missed? I sure didn't see one but the configuration of ConEmu is a bit... jumbled.

You'd think it would be on the Mark & Paste screen:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Update to a version >= 120617a
2. Option "Auto copy" on the "Mark & Paste" page. Check it.

[image: ConEmu 120617a]

**Please note.** In latest developer builds (like 120717) option was renamed to "Copy on LButton up"

[image: ConEmu 120717]

Comment: Yeah? I sure don't see it. Added the screen to the OP.

Comment: @jcollum You should've mentioned the version. The versions in both screenshots do not match. ;)

Comment: Check Whats new, new options appears quickly ;)  http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Whats_New

Comment: @iglvzx indeed. I just downloaded this app last week. Apparently Auto Copy was added between now and then. 120617a.x64 has it.

Comment: I had to turn off the Left Shift modifier on Text Selection to get this to work.

Comment: @Maximus here's a feature request: selecting across lines and copying text results in 1 line when pasted -- my #1 complaint about windows cmd/powershell vs bash

Comment: I thought about it, but have not found accurate method of "real \r\n" detection. So, was postponed. Only way I see - if end of console line has more than two spases - it is "new line"

Comment: in latest version, under keys & Macro --> Mark & Paste --> Text Selection: select with mouse, you can select using left Shift key by default.

Comment: How do you disable it in the current alpha version? I unticked Copy on Left Button release, but it still does it.

Comment: Just checked. It does not.