# ConEmu disable copy selection

Tags: conemu

I have already looked at someone trying the opposite: [can I get ConEmu to "mark to copy"?](https://superuser.com/questions/438472/can-i-get-conemu-to-mark-to-copy), but I had already tried unchecking "Copy on Left Button release".

I'm running ConEmu 140216b, installed(as opposed to portable), on win7.
Off chance it matters, running kitty(a putty fork, with updates) as the console.

It is an alpha build, and as there are no stable builds on the download page, should I just try installing the preview build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be obviously that KiTTY is **not** a console application! KiTTY is another **GUI** application. And it process mouse and keyboard input **internally**! ConEmu can't change behavior of another GUI terminal emulator, goto KiTTY settings.

Comment: ...Right, makes sense now that it's been pointed out.